# Unexpected SignatureConfirmation in IssuedTokenOverTransport response

Tags: c#, wcf, interop

I am building a WCF client to access a vendor web service. The service uses IssuedTokenOverTransport, SymmetricKey, and expects SAML. I have the request working, but the response back from the service includes a SignatureConfirmation element in the WS-Security header. My C# client chokes on this "signature confirmation is not expected in the security header" and I don't see a way to either ignore or process this element. It seems the only way to get near the handling of SignatureConfirmation in WCF is to abandon the IssuedTokenOverTransport binding and use something else, but this doesn't seem to be an option because the service requires this binding type. Is this a bug in WCF?

Comment: Running into the same thing here...almost exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using a custom Message Encoder. See this article from Carlos Figueroa for background:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/11/09/wcf-extensibility-message-encoders.aspx

Essentially, the encoder can look for the SignatureConfirmation element in the incoming message and remove it from the header. The key piece of code is this private method that is called from the ReadMessage overrides:

```
    private MemoryStream ProcessMemoryStream(Stream inputStream, bool dispose)
    {
        StreamWriter xmlStream = null;
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        bool continueFilter = false;
        try
        {
            xmlStream = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(inputStream))
            {
                using (
                    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(xmlStream,
                        new XmlWriterSettings() {ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto}))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.LocalName.Equals("SignatureConfirmation") &&
                            reader.NamespaceURI.Equals(
                                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"))
                        {
                            if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) continueFilter = reader.IsStartElement();
                        }
                        else if (reader.LocalName.Equals("Signature") &&
                                 reader.NamespaceURI.Equals("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"))
                        {
                            if (!reader.IsEmptyElement) continueFilter = reader.IsStartElement();
                        }
                        else if (continueFilter)
                        {
                           // continue to next node
                        }
                        else
                            XmlHelper.WriteShallowNode(reader, writer);
                    }
                    writer.Flush();
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            outputStream.Position = 0;
            return outputStream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle error
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xmlStream != null && dispose) xmlStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The Xml Helper:

```
internal static class XmlHelper
{
    internal static void WriteShallowNode(XmlReader reader, XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (reader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        }
        if (writer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
        }

        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                writer.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Name);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                writer.WriteDocType(reader.Name, reader.GetAttribute("PUBLIC"), reader.GetAttribute("SYSTEM"),
                    reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```